# Detecting iOS devices that browse to rails site through an App (ie. Twitter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, mobile, user-agent

I'm using this piece of code that is working correctly to detect iOS devices when browsing through the Safari browser:

```
def mobile_user_agent?
@mobile_user_agent ||= ( request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] && request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]   [/(Mobile\/.+Safari)/] )
end
```

But it doesn't detect a user coming to the site through an App's browser on the device. Mainly Twitter.

I believe this is the UA for a twitter user, so how do you accomodate for this (and other Apps as well?)

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9A405"
```

Comment: If you're detecting mobile devices in order to serve them different page layouts, you probably don't want to: http://farukat.es/journal/2011/02/499-lest-we-forget-or-how-i-learned-whats-so-bad-about-browser-sniffing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i would do is change the regex to something like

```
/(Mobile\/.+Safari)|(AppleWebKit\/.+Mobile)/
```

Comment: FYI, this regex also matches mobile Chrome on Android, which is probably not what you want.